# Lighting in 3D Ursina Games

Tags: python, ursina

I just started learning the [Ursina](https://www.ursinaengine.org/) game engine and I was wondering if there was any way to add lighting against entities. I'm trying to make an FPS game and it seems I can't find anything on the topic of lighting! It surprising and frustrating so, please help me out. :)

Comment: Have a look at the [Ursina cheat sheet](https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet.html#Light). The built-in [FPS sample](https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/blob/master/samples/fps.py) uses DirectionalLight.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way:

```
for x in range(some_intager):
    for z in range(some_other_intager):
        Entity(model='cube', x=x, z=z, shader=lit_with_shadows_shader)
DirectionalLight(parent=pivot, y=2, z=3, shadows=True, rotation=(45, -45, 45))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can offer is that you make a nested for loop above the map and place objects.

Here is the code:

```
for x in range(some_intager):
    for z in range(some_other_intager):
        Entity(model='cube', x=x, z=z, shader=lit_with_shadows_shader)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add lights (`directional`, `point`, `spot` or `ambient`). And then use a shader like `lit_with_shadows_shader`. The code will be:

```py
from ursina import *
from ursina.shaders import lit_with_shadows_shader


class Lights:
        def __init__(self):
            self.pivot = Entity()
            self.direc_light = DirectionalLight(parent=self.pivot, y=2, z=3, shadows=True, rotation=(45, -45, 45))
            self.amb_light = AmbientLight(parent=self.pivot, color = color.rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1))



app = Ursina()

# Set shader to all entities
Entity.default_shader = lit_with_shadows_shader



# Lights
Lights()
pivot = Lights().pivot
direc_light = Lights().direc_light
amb_light = Lights().amb_light


# Create entity
cube1 = Entity(model='plane', color = color.blue, position = (0,0,0), scale=(10,10,0), collider='box')
cube2 = Entity(model='cube', color = color.red, position = (3,3,0), collider='box')



app.run()
```